# Notational inquiry regarding nuclear chemistry

Tags: notation, nuclear-chemistry

I'm aware that the notation for an element (with a charge) is as follows:

$$\large ^{~~~\text{mass number}}_{\text{atomic number}}(\text{element symbol})^{\text{charge}}$$

However, during beta decay (of a neutron to a proton and a negatively charged electron) we write it almost as if the beta decay emitted two negatively charged electrons. Allow me to explain.

$\ce{^14_6C -> ^14_7N + ^0_{-1}e}$ is the reaction of negative beta decay of carbon-14. But, the fact that in the right side of the reaction we wrote $\ce{^14_7N}$ by itself already means that has a charge of 0. The issue here is that every proton has a positive charge of 1, and so this means there must be another negatively charged electron we haven't accounted for (since the other one that is emitted appears to not be in this consideration, because if it was already summed then we'd have $\ce{^14_7N-}$ in the right-side of the reaction.

Any clarification would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You do realize $\ce{_6^{14}C}$ and $\ce{_7^{14}N}$ are *nuclei*, don't you?

Comment: Yes, that's the notation of the things inside the nuclei. However, for $^{14}_{7}N$ to have a neutral charge wouldn't that mean we had to emit another negative-charged electron on top of the one that split off, the ^{0}_{-1} e? 

For example, when I read $^{14}_{7} N$ I assume that means its charge is neutral.

Comment: You can use `$\ce{^14_7N}$` instead, it comes out much better. When you write `$^{14}_7 N$`, there are a couple of problems: firstly the TeX / MathJax engine thinks that you're trying to apply the super/subscripts to whatever came *before* it. This is less problematic if there's nothing that comes before it, but in the equation in your original question, it was trying to attach them to the plus sign. Next, the alignment is kinda wrong; you want the super- and subscripts to be right-aligned. Thirdly, the N comes out italicised, whereas chemical symbols should be upright.

Comment: Appreciate it orthocresol, will apply that.

Comment: Nuclear physics folk generally ignore what all happens to the electrons. Partly they just don't care much about those light weight gnats buzzing around the nucleus, but also because an energetic charged particle departing the nucleus (beta, positron, alpha) may well cause some undetermined number of electrons to fly away as well, so there is no unique balance of electrons on the remaining nucleus.

Comment: I see Jon Custer, so you are saying that they write the resulting nucleus as if its neutral charge but completely ignore whether it actually is a neutral charge or not. That is honestly very helpful and I really appreciate it. I try to understand things to the best extent rather than just skipping them, hence this question which may seem basic but also unorthodox in a way.